# Java Play Framework - NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration

Tags: java, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I've just startet to work with the Java Play Framework and made some steps forward but now i intended to add the JavaEbean OEM and i went through the documentation but still get the error **NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration**

application.conf

```
    # This is the main configuration file for the application.
    # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ConfigFile

    ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.0")
```

My Model:

```
import io.ebean.Model;

public class Book extends Model {..}
```

build.sbt

```
name := """BookStoreApp"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += guice
```

i started with sbt, made the updates everything is fine, but if i compile, im getting the following error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration
[error]         at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:27)
[error]         at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:21)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$4(PlayEbean.scala:153)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.withClassLoader$1(PlayEbean.scala:130)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$1(PlayEbean.scala:150)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.Configuration
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[error]         at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:27)
[error]         at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:21)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$4(PlayEbean.scala:153)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.withClassLoader$1(PlayEbean.scala:130)
[error]         at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$1(PlayEbean.scala:150)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (Compile / playEbeanModels) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 22.02.2019 10:07:26
```

**if i run sbt run im getting the same error as above, plus:**

```
 [error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Internal server error, sending 500 response
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
        at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
        at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
        at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:504)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
[error] (Compile / playEbeanModels) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration
```

Comment: Do you have a database connection configured in your `conf/application.conf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the `play` or `ebean` versions.

The `play` has changed the default `Configuration` class in the 2.7: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaConfigMigration26.

The `ebean` plugin versions and it correspondence to the `play`:
https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean#releases

So the next

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.0")
```

must be changed to

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.21")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.0")
```

or

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.0")
```

Comment: As i've seen it on a github report post, version 2.7.0 is somehow instable using ebean 5.0.0. Changing to play Version 2.6.6 and Ebean 4.6.1 did solve the problem! Thank you

Comment: *sbt-play-ebean v5.0.0* is not installable, so *v5.0.1* can be used with *play v2.7.0*

Comment: on Play 2.8.8 I was receiving a similar error but it went away when i removed     ```ebean.default = ["models.*"]```